# Set batch file variable to the output of a Powshell script

Tags: powershell, batch-file

This powershell script accepts an argument and returns a value:

**decrypt_password.ps1**

```
# Decrypts KMS Encrypted password payload by executing the "aws kms decrypt" command
# Arguments: File path containing a password payload as CypherTextBlob
# Returns: Decrypted Password

$file_path=$args[0]

# Remove encryption
$encoded_pass = aws kms decrypt --ciphertext-blob "fileb://$file_path" --query Plaintext --output text --region us-east-1

# Remove base64 encoding from pass
$decrypted = [Text.Encoding]::Utf8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($encoded_pass))

return $decrypted
```

Then in this batch file I would like to set a variable to the output of this script. I have tried the below command, but it simply sets the value of PASS to the entire string... it does not call the function

```
set PASS = powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "C:\installation_files\decrypt_password.ps1 'C:\installation_files\encrypted'"
```

How can get the output of `decrypt_password.ps1` stored in the PASS variable?

Comment: @SomethingDark yes it does

Comment: Oh, that's just what they changed the "possible duplicate of..." text to; it wasn't a real question.